# Follow active quads does not "flatten" all the poligons

Tags: uv

I modeled the U.S.S. Enterprise NCC-1701 and my next step is to unwrap it before texturing.

At the moment, I'm working on the unwrapping of the "disk part", but I'm having some problem. Here you can find an image:

[image]

What I would like to do is to use "Follow active quads" to "flatten" horizontally the UV map and texture it easily. However, it seems that "Follow active quads" doesn't work completely.

In my example (the image), some parts don't get flatten horizontally (in red). It seems that this behaviour is caused by the extra details in the pulse propulsion.

I had a similar problem with the upper and lower part of the disk, connected to the pulse propulsion (in yellow). It's not shown in the image, but I tried to put an extra seam to flatten horizontally the upper disk (in pink) and I could not flatten the yellow parts.

Hopefully I was clear enough on the explanation. If not, feel free to ask.

**EDIT 1:**
Blender file available [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkFTgZyIwsOp3xEX0mvqc6E40kb-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Don't know how you got that. I rebuilt your mesh and I don't get that. And also you have ngones which is not good for your topology or your unwrap. So maybe correct this, select your mesh again and <kbd>U</kbd> > *Reset*, and again select your ring, select a quad of your ring, and <kbd>U</kbd> > *Follow Active Quad*.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. But, look, your model is different than mine. In the red and yellow parts, there are more details made with "subdivide". Moreover, the red parts have a different angle with respect to the other poligons in the side part of the disk. If this degree of details is not enough, can it help if I upload the file?

Comment: yes please upload

Comment: I edited the question. You can find it there.

Comment: again, it looks like it can't work with your current topology because the active quad needs to be a quad and if you choose a quad in your ring it will cut off your ring. You really need to make a good topology for this reason and many others, always try to avoid ngons

Comment: Just one more question before leaving: if you had been me, would you have done the propulsion using loop subdivide?

Comment: I read my previous message and I don't even remember what I meant, anyway, yes, try not to use ngons, use quads, and tris if you can't avoid it. For the propulsion, I'm not sure what you mean, yes you can subdivide as long as it gives a good topology.